# Wired/Ethernet option not displayed in Network Settings

Tags: networking

I can see the wired icon showing wired unmanaged but when I try to open Wired settings, it only shows VPN and Proxy. I am new to Linux OS (Dual booted for the first time today). I reinstalled the OS, but it didn't help. **I am using Ubuntu 20.04.05**

What do I do?

Edit:
I did this:
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
and changed managed=false to managed=true.
Now I can see the wired option in settings, but it doesn't connect to the internet. It shows " ? " symbol on wired connection. Any advice on what to do?

Comment: are you using a USB ethernet adapter? if so try another one.

Comment: It works for Windows, so I doubt that it's an adapter problem.

Comment: not really, Ubuntu's management of USB adapters has been , to say the least, variable for me for 4 years. I have more than 6 adapters. USB 3.1 and USB-C   .  and even this week sometimes waking up from suspend straight away, I had to kill the nordvpn process. then it worked. mercurial, it pays to experiment.